# FPDF error: This document (mine.pdf) probably uses a compression technique which is not supported by the free parser shipped with FPDI

Tags: php, pdf

How to settle down the problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO. The error message sounds pretty clear. Do you need help understanding it, or hints for workarounds?

Comment: I too ran into this problem when upgrading from an older version of FPDI. If you found a good solution, please let us know

Comment: Those are not actually answers, that code is released with apache license and compression technics are not secrets. Buying makes it hard to configure server, also it is not an open code, where I can throw exception instead of die (I can't know if there is die in the closed source). I do not want to be polemic I just want to know if there are opposition on write down that code and releasing it with the same license.
I also read JM4 comment, really this appear in newer version? where is the older? (look like questions, but hide an answer, don't find?)

Answer (score 5):

When making your template, export it using the "PDF-A - 1a" export setting. (In Acrobat Pro you may SAVE AS with this setting)

More details: (MAC OSX but shoudl work for WIN as well)
Open your pdf in acrobat pro.
Save as -> MORE OPTIONS -> PDF/A
in the popup screen, press settings

In this screen make sure the option "CREATE PDF/A-1a according to the profile bla bla" and select CONVERT TO PDF/A-1a (sRGB)
printing conditions: sRGB
apply corrections = checked

now save and finish.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this exact same problem recently. I was able to solve the problem using this gentleman's PDF parser, which replaces the free one in FPDI. Granted, you will be paying 100 Euros for it, but if you need to have your software work for PDFs that use later compression algorithms, this is probably the best way to go:

http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi-pdf-parser/

I have used it, and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

[Gavin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1175089/321749) worked around this problem by converting it down to pdf 1.4, I suggest you try the same before buying the expensive pdf.