# FPDF error: This document (testcopy.pdf) probably uses a compression technique which is not supported by the free parser shipped with FPDI

Tags: php, fpdf, fpdi

I am running the following code and giving me this error : `FPDF error: This document (testcopy.pdf) probably uses a compression technique which is not supported by the free parser shipped with FPDI.` I used another pdf named `test.pdf` and that works fine but it is giving me error in `testcopy.pdf.`

I think this is parser problem. Anyone know any other parser that can be used with fpdf to avoid this error?

**My code:**

```
require('fpdf17/fpdf.php'); 
require('fpdf17/fpdi.php'); 
// initiate FPDI 
$pdf = new FPDI(); 
while (ob_get_level())
ob_end_clean();
header("Content-Encoding: None", true);
// set the sourcefile 
$pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile('testcopy.pdf');
```

I want to split pdf in two pdfs and want to attach both pdfs in file attachments field.How to save pdf to server. Can it be possible with fpdf?

Comment: I have not faced such issue before. BTW, here is a similar question which might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441107/fpdf-error-this-document-mine-pdf-probably-uses-a-compression-technique-which

Comment: thnx.. i checked this question but didn't help me.. i want to know if there is any parser can be used with fpdf??? I think Fpdi didn't support all type pdf format.

Answer (score 53):

Yes, Exactly the FPDF library supports only PDF version 1.4 & lesser. So to over come from this issue use [GhostScript](http://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html). This script helps to change the PDF versions dynamically.

(1) Download the [Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html) here.

(2) Install the Ghostscript and define the environment variable PATH.

(3) Then, use the below php code to change the PDF version.

```
shell_exec( "gswin32 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=".$new_pdf." ".$old_pdf."");
```

(4) Now we get PDF with version 1.4 as output, then continue with FPDF.

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for this ! I had to change `gswin32` to `gs` for this to work

Comment: What do you mean by "define the environment variable PATH"? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Marsha It means you should add the path of ghostscript executable to the PATH variable on your Windows OS. search this keyword and it will tell you how. "adding path to windows"

Comment: This should be marked as answer this is so far the very best shot I saw.

Comment: this link shows how it is done using a full practical example, it may help someone:
http://www.infoconic.com/blog/trick-for-fpdi-pdf-parser-that-supports-pdf-version-above-1-4/

Answer (score 28):

I had the same issue that PDFMerger does not work with certain PDF.
It seems that Adobe keep updating compression way of pdf extension.

I found solution with Chrome.

```
1. Open the PDF file(which does not work with PDFMerger) with Chrome
2. Right Click and Print
3. Change destination as [Save as PDF]
4. This exported PDF file is compatible with PDFMerger
```

Comment: I used to use Ghostscript to do this but this does indeed work, way more convenient. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

Looking through the answers so far, I wasn't able to resolve the issue.
Here's why and you may have the same issue so this answer would be invaluable to you too.

I did not have access to acrobat, so I couldn't downgrade the version of the original PDF. I wasn't in a position to purchase the newer version of the library which has upgraded encryption.

In the end I used an online PDF converter to downgrade my PDF file to version 5 (1.4)

If you are not able to find one, here's a link for completeness.

```
https://docupub.com/pdfconvert/
```

(bear in mind that the contents of a link may change)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. By far the easiest approach.

Comment: Thank you! You save my time! Best answer))

Answer (score 15):

The file needs to be PDF 1.4 (Acrobat 5) or lower. If you have Adobe Acrobat Pro you can change this with  Document->Decrease File Size.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my answer from another topic:

"It can be overcome by re-saving the template and change compression type.
In Adobe Acrobat Pro go to File->Save As->Optimised PDF-> Popup left list - Clean Up,
Object Compression Options -> Change to "Compress document structure" -> OK to save"

Ref. [Editing password protected pdfs with fpdi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13120825/editing-password-protected-pdfs-with-fpdi)

Answer (score 3):

GPL Ghostscript 8.70 (2009-07-31) / Centos 7

```
ghostscript -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=new_file.pdf file.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

For those that don't have any of the pro versions of Acrobat:

I was having this problem with new versions of Word when trying to use the Office functionality to save to a PDF. It seems the PDF conversion tool supplied in Office is using the newer formats.  Here's how I fixed it.

- Install NitroPDF free version (May work with another free PDF creator that can be downloaded)
- Go to the Word document and select 'Print'.
- In the print options, instead of your printer, select 'Nitro PDF Creator (Reader 3)' or whatever the current version is.
- A dialog box will open and allow you to select where to save the PDF.

The version saved was able to be opened by FPDF.

Hope it helps

Comment: Chrome seems to do the same thing, open in Google Chrome and print as PDF

Answer (score 1):

In the case of Mac, you can open the PDF file in Preview and "export as PDF". The exported one can then be used.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar error like you. My solution was to convert the pdf to a lower pdf version. Than everything worked like expected.

I hope that simple trick will help you!

Comment: i know that i was asking about another parser that can be used with fpdf that support all type version.