# Merging two PDF using PHP (for version > 1.4)

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf

I have a issue of merging two pdf into one pdf. I am using FPDF + FPDI and also tried TCPDF + FPDI, However i had a problem when I am using pdf version > 1.4 The php error is : FPDF error: This document (pdf_dump/1407303457.pdf) probably uses a compression technique which is not supported by the free parser shipped with FPDI.

I do not want to use the commercial plugin of fpdi. Is there any work around available to work with pdf > 1.4 version.

NB: I am using codeigniter

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12154190/fpdf-error-this-document-testcopy-pdf-probably-uses-a-compression-technique-w).

You need to save your PDF as an earlier version, PDF 1.4 or lower, and then it should hopefully work with FPDF.

---

You can try the [TCPDI Parser](https://github.com/pauln/tcpdi), it is a modified version of FPDI which should support PDF version > 1.4

Comment: I saw it, but I am developing the website and other people will be using it. I cannot request other users to save PDF to earlier version and upload. Hope you understand my situation !!

Comment: I shall try TCPDI Parser and let me see if it works for version > 1.4

Comment: It is not working. It is giving an error on using.

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'TCPDF_PARSER ERROR: decodeFilterFlateDecode: invalid code' in C:\wamp\www\pdftest\tcpdf\include\tcpdf_filters.php on line 474

Exception: TCPDF_PARSER ERROR: decodeFilterFlateDecode: invalid code in C:\wamp\www\pdftest\tcpdf\include\tcpdf_filters.php on line 474

Comment: And what is line 474? Try creating a really simple code example and see if that works.

Comment: I researched and found out that it was caused due to Password protected/ secured PDF file (I missed it earlier). The PDF > 1.4 version is getting merged smoothly now.

However a new problem occured, when the file is password protected/ secured. Is there any method in php/codeigniter to check if the pdf is password protected ?

Comment: You can have a look at https://www.drupal.org/node/843516, however I recommend you to start a new question if you want further help with it :)

Comment: @SomnathPaul I'm having the same problem but the PDFs are not password protected. However, has come to my knowledge that the users were splitting the PDF's pages in 2 files(my process needs 2 files) and the software used is causing the issue

Answer (score 1):

For symfony, I used this lib to convert pdf>1.4 to pdf1.4 :

https://packagist.org/packages/xthiago/pdf-version-converter

Comment: I'm the author of `xthiago/pdf-version-converter`. The library can be used in any PHP project - it no requires the use of Symfony Framework (Full Stack). The library internally uses two components of Symfony (process and filesystem), but composer takes care about it. I recommend you the use of the library because it has unit tests (PHPUnit) and is open-source - you can benefit of bug fixes and enhancements made by community.