# Downgrade PDF version with Ghostscript 8.70: A pdfmark destination page 34 points beyond the last page 22

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, ghostscript

**Background**

- My requirement is a feature to watermark PDF docs on demand within a LAMP stack (PHP 7.3).
- The webapp has a collection of PDF docs loaded into a MySQL table. The docs originated as PDF files with various versions of PDF.
- My watermarking solution is based on [this article using FPDF](https://phppot.com/php/php-watermark-pdf/).
- I had the problem in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12154190).
- So I added Ghostscript to the flow, to downgrade all docs to PDF 1.4.

**Ghostscript Command**

```
 gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=/tmp/63d319f2d1018.pdf /tmp/63d319f2cfb51.pdf
```

**Error for one problem doc**

- For most docs, the flow is working and adding watermarks.
- However, for one doc so far, Ghostscript fails as shown below.
- The original PDF content, i.e. the input to GhostScript, renders fine in browsers and Acrobat Reader.
- Here is the Ghostscript error (sorry for the formatting):

> Error: /rangecheck in --makepattern-- Operand stack: --dict:11/20(L)-- --dict:14/23(L)-- --dict:14/23(L)-- --nostringval-- false --dict:14/15(L)-- --nostringval-- Execution stack: %interp_exit .runexec2 --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 %stopped_push --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- false 1 %stopped_push 1862 1 3 %oparray_pop 1861 1 3 %oparray_pop 1845 1 3 %oparray_pop --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 24 1 34 --nostringval-- %for_pos_int_continue --nostringval-- --nostringval-- false 1 %stopped_push --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- %array_continue --nostringval-- false 1 %stopped_push --nostringval-- %loop_continue --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 1811 4 10 %oparray_pop --nostringval-- Dictionary stack: --dict:1150/1684(ro)(G)-- --dict:1/20(G)-- --dict:76/200(L)-- --dict:76/200(L)-- --dict:106/127(ro)(G)-- --dict:286/300(ro)(G)-- --dict:22/25(L)-- --dict:4/6(L)-- --dict:25/40(L)-- --dict:3/5(L)-- Current allocation mode is local Last OS error: 2 GPL Ghostscript 8.70: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1 GPL Ghostscript 8.70: ERROR: A pdfmark destination page 34 points beyond the last page 22.

Is there a better Ghostscript command? Or a better approach?

Comment: I've updated the post indicating that this PDF doc is working otherwise. Maybe there is some "PDF lint" program to make it work in Ghostscript?

Comment: The website and content are not public. Sorry, I can't share the specific document.

Comment: You could try [PDFtk Server](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/) to uncompress and recompress the PDF.

Comment: The problem isn't the 'pdfmark destination....', that occurs because an annotation has a destination which is a page number that doesn't exist in the document. Ghostscript simply ignores it (but tells you about it). Your real problem is the 'rangecheck in --makepattern'. This is almost certainly a bug in th einterpreter, and it has almost certainly been fixed. Try using a version of Ghostscript less than 13 years old!

Comment: @KenS Finally got back to this after time sharing with two other projects. I built the latest Ghostscript, and presto, the app works.

Answer (score 0):

You ask if there is a better approach?
So yes, use the second more modern transparent watermark underlay system. By way of explanation here is that 1st type of watermark in the brand leader browser Edge/Chrome and same online file (without the watermark) in a competitive browser viewer where we can remove that annoying feature of obliterating contents. However in all cases **GhostScript cannot work with broken files** That file probably needs open in Acrobat to fix it. Also note watermarks can be removed by Browsers editors or any PDF Viewer/Editor.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the post to indicate that the original PDF doc, the input to Ghostscript, works fine in browsers and Acrobat.