# Which PDF-Library can add pages in an existing PDF > 1.4?

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, zend-pdf, pdflib

I need to add pages in an existing PDF document after the first page and as last page.
I used to implement it with Zend_Pdf but found out, that it can only handle PDFs of which the cross-reference table isn't compressed to a stream (a feature that was introduced in PDF version 1.5).

So I'm looking for a PHP PDF-Library which can modify existing PDF documents with objects and an xref table stored in a stream as described in ISO-32000-1 (which was based on PDF-1.7).

- [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org) cannot modify, only in combination with [FPDI](http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/) (and FPDI can only handle PDF-Version up to 1.4 in the free version)
- Zend_PDF (as mentioned above) can only handle files to PDF Version up to 1.4. Maybe it would be an idea to try the Zend_Pdf Version from ZF2 from github?
- FPDF can only handle files to PDF Version 1.4 as I found out

Are there any other PHP PDF libraries for my needs?

Comment: Have you actually run into any problems with Zend_Pdf? Pages are well-defined separate objects in PDF, so if you open a PDF file with Zend_Pdf and all you do is add a number of additional pages, chances are very high (if Zend_Pdf behaves nicely) that things will simply continue to work.

Comment: Yes, i had problems with a PDF in Version 1.5. 
Error: "Cross-reference streams are not supported yet."

Comment: @DavidvanDriessche According to [Zend_Pdf Einführung](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/de/zend.pdf.introduction.html#fnid1) only loading of V1.4 (Acrobat 5) PDF documents is supported. I assume that means cross reference streams are not supported. rescueAnn seems to require support of them.

Answer (score 0):

it seem that FPDI can do a mergin of different pdf document, so you can build you first page an then your other pages and merge it into one with a specified order ([Merge PDF files with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794435/merge-pdf-files-with-php))

```
class concat_pdf extends FPDI {
     var $files = array();
     function setFiles($files) {
          $this->files = $files;
     }
     function concat() {
          foreach($this->files AS $file) {
               $pagecount = $this->setSourceFile($file);
               for ($i = 1; $i <= $pagecount; $i++) {
                    $tplidx = $this->ImportPage($i);
                    $s = $this->getTemplatesize($tplidx);
                    $this->AddPage('P', array($s['w'], $s['h']));
                    $this->useTemplate($tplidx);
               }
          }
     }
}

/* uses example :
$pdf =& new concat_pdf();
$pdf->setFiles(array("doc.pdf","pauta.pdf", "4bp.pdf", "5bp.pdf"));
$pdf->concat();
//$pdf->Output("newpdf.pdf", "I");//for printing on screen
$pdf->Output("newpdf.pdf", "F");//for saving it
*/
```

but for version above 1.4 there is a new conpression used and FPDI support it witha parser bundle but it is not free of charge (100€). you can have a look there [Is there a way to make FPDF/FPDI or Zend_Pdf support the parsing of PDFs greater than 1.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660425/is-there-a-way-to-make-fpdf-fpdi-or-zend-pdf-support-the-parsing-of-pdfs-greater) too.

Comment: You're right. But actually I was looking for a free possibility to do the merging.
If I won't find one, I'll keep that in mind. Buying PDFlib would be much more expensive anyway.